# dlibをインストールしようとするとcv2が見つからないというエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python, 機械学習, opencv, コマンドプロンプト

https://www.kkaneko.jp/dblab/dlib/trydlib.html
上のサイトを参考にしてdlibのインストールを進めていたのですが

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
py -m pip install -U numpy scikit-image scikit-learn
```

のコマンドを管理者からコマンドプロンプトで実行するとエラーは起きないのですが
そのあとバージョン確認のコマンドを実行してみるとcv2が見つからないとエラーが出てしまいます。

一回アンインストールしてから再度インストールしてみても同じエラーが出てしまいました。
解決法などがあれば教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
c:\pytools\imutils>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
copying build\lib\imutils\contours.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\convenience.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\encodings.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\face_utils\facealigner.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils
copying build\lib\imutils\face_utils\helpers.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils
copying build\lib\imutils\face_utils\__init__.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\dense.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\factories.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\gftt.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\harris.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\helpers.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\rootsift.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\feature\__init__.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature
copying build\lib\imutils\io\tempfile.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\io
copying build\lib\imutils\io\__init__.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\io
copying build\lib\imutils\meta.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\object_detection.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\paths.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\perspective.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\text.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
copying build\lib\imutils\video\count_frames.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\video\filevideostream.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\video\fps.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\video\pivideostream.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\video\videostream.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\video\webcamvideostream.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\video\__init__.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video
copying build\lib\imutils\__init__.py -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\contours.py to contours.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py to convenience.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\encodings.py to encodings.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils\facealigner.py to facealigner.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils\helpers.py to helpers.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\dense.py to dense.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\factories.py to factories.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\gftt.py to gftt.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\harris.py to harris.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\helpers.py to helpers.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\rootsift.py to rootsift.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\feature\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\io\tempfile.py to tempfile.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\io\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\meta.py to meta.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\object_detection.py to object_detection.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\paths.py to paths.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\perspective.py to perspective.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\text.py to text.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\count_frames.py to count_frames.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\filevideostream.py to filevideostream.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\fps.py to fps.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\pivideostream.py to pivideostream.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\videostream.py to videostream.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\webcamvideostream.py to webcamvideostream.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\video\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
running install_scripts
copying build\scripts-3.7\range-detector -> C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils-0.5.3-py3.7.egg-info
Writing C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\imutils-0.5.3-py3.7.egg-info
```

```
c:\pytools\imutils>py -c "import imutils; print( imutils.__version__ )"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\pytools\imutils\imutils\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "c:\pytools\imutils\imutils\convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

```
c:\pytools\imutils>pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ -----------
absl-py                  0.9.0
astunparse               1.6.3
attrs                    19.3.0
cachetools               4.1.1
certifi                  2020.6.20
chardet                  3.0.4
cycler                   0.10.0
decorator                4.4.2
dill                     0.3.2
dlib                     19.20.99
face-alignment           1.0.1
future                   0.18.2
gast                     0.3.3
google-auth              1.18.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
google-pasta             0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
grpcio                   1.30.0
h5py                     2.10.0
idna                     2.10
imageio                  2.8.0
importlib-metadata       1.7.0
imutils                  0.5.3
Keras                    2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.2
kiwisolver               1.2.0
Markdown                 3.2.2
matplotlib               3.2.2
networkx                 2.4
numpy                    1.19.0
oauthlib                 3.1.0
opencv-python            4.2.0.34
opt-einsum               3.2.1
Pillow                   7.1.2
pip                      20.1.1
promise                  2.3
protobuf                 3.12.2
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pyparsing                2.4.7
python-dateutil          2.8.1
PyWavelets               1.1.1
PyYAML                   5.3.1
requests                 2.24.0
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
rsa                      4.6
scikit-image             0.17.2
scipy                    1.4.1
setuptools               47.1.0
six                      1.15.0
tensorboard              2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit   1.7.0
tensorflow-datasets      3.1.0
tensorflow-gpu           2.2.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator 2.2.0
tensorflow-metadata      0.22.2
termcolor                1.1.0
tifffile                 2020.6.3
torch                    1.5.1+cu101
torchvision              0.6.1+cu101
tqdm                     4.47.0
urllib3                  1.25.9
Werkzeug                 1.0.1
wheel                    0.34.2
wrapt                    1.12.1
zipp                     3.1.0

c:\pytools\imutils>
```

Comment: 参考になさっているサイトにopencvのインストールの説明もあるようですが、 https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/cv2.html この範囲がうまく行っているか、確認なさってはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 確認しても同じエラーが起こってしまいます。一回opencvのファイルを削除して最初からそのページのインストール手順試すのは意味ありますか？

Comment: 何かしら参照先の前提とする動作環境や作業手順とは違っているのでは？ 1度試して駄目だったのなら、本当は何が悪いのかがわからないと、個々のモジュールのアンインストール/再インストール程度では上手くいかない可能性があります。一番大掛かりな方法としてはPythonのアンインストール/再インストールまで行うことでしょうか。 ちなみにエラーが発生しているのは`dlib`のインストールでは無く`imutils`のインストール後チェックのようですが。

Comment: 確認の分解能を、知識を獲得しながら上げていくといいと思います。インストールされているファイルを調べてみて、cやc++で実装されているopencvそのものはインストールされているように見えるか？そしてpythonのパッケージのcv2はインストールされているように見えるか？ファイルがあってしかるべき場所に見あたらなければ、opencv-python単独のインストールをやってみて、エラーが出ないか確認する。といったことを自分ならやってみます。